# After inserting an apply instead of loop

Tags: r, performance

I changed my dataset to data.table and I'm using sapply (apply family) but so far that wasn't sufficiant. Is this fully correct?

I already went from this:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

buying_volume_before_breakout <- list()
for (e in 1:length(df_1_30sec_5min$date_time)) {

  interval <- dolar_tick_data_unified_dt[date_time <= df_1_30sec_5min$date_time[e] &
                                           date_time >= df_1_30sec_5min$date_time[e] - time_to_collect_volume &
                                           Type == "Buyer"]

  buying_volume_before_breakout[[e]] <- sum(interval$Quantity)
}
```

To this (created a function and and using sapply)

```
fun_buying_volume_before_breakout <- function(e) {
  interval <- dolar_tick_data_unified_dt[date_time <= df_1_30sec_5min$date_time[e] &
                                           date_time >= df_1_30sec_5min$date_time[e] - time_to_collect_volume &
                                           Type == "Buyer"]
  return(sum(interval$Quantity))
}
buying_volume_before_breakout <- sapply(1:length(df_1_30sec_5min$date_time), fun_buying_volume_before_breakout)
```

I couldn't make my data reproducible but here are some more insights about its structure.

```
> str(dolar_tick_data_unified_dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3120650 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ date_time  : POSIXct, format: "2017-06-02 09:00:35" "2017-06-02 09:00:35" "2017-06-02 09:00:35" ...
 $ Buyer_from : Factor w/ 74 levels "- - ","- - BGC LIQUIDEZ DTVM",..: 29 44 19 44 44 44 44 17 17 17 ...
 $ Price      : num  3271 3271 3272 3271 3271 ...
 $ Quantity   : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 10 5 50 25 ...
 $ Seller_from: Factor w/ 73 levels "- - ","- - BGC LIQUIDEZ DTVM",..: 34 34 42 28 28 28 28 34 45 28 ...
 $ Type       : Factor w/ 4 levels "Buyer","Direct",..: 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 


> str(df_1_30sec_5min)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3001 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ date_time                    : POSIXct, format: "2017-06-02 09:33:30" "2017-06-02 09:49:38" "2017-06-02 10:00:41" ...
 $ Price                        : num  3251 3252 3256 3256 3260 ...
 $ fast_small_mm                : num  3250 3253 3254 3256 3259 ...
 $ slow_small_mm                : num  3254 3253 3254 3256 3259 ...
 $ fast_big_mm                  : num  3255 3256 3256 3256 3258 ...
 $ slow_big_mm                  : num  3258 3259 3260 3261 3262 ...
 $ breakout_strength            : num  6.5 2 0.5 2 2.5 0.5 1 2.5 1 0.5 ...
 $ buying_volume_before_breakout: num  1285 485 680 985 820 ...
 $ total_volume_before_breakout : num  1285 485 680 985 820 ...
 $ average_buying_volume        : num  1158 338 318 394 273 ...
 $ average_total_volume         : num  1158 338 318 394 273 ...
 $ relative_strenght            : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ relative_strenght_last_6min  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: why couldn't you make the data reproducible? Even just a sample of it?what does 'should I ex' mean? what is the desired output? What i going wrong here that you need help with?

Comment: maybe something like `dolar_tick_data_unified_dt[Type=="Buyer"][df_1_30sec_5min[, c("start","end") := .(date_time, date_time-time_to_collect_volume)], .(date_time<=start, date_time>=end), by=.EACHI sum(Quantity)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, separate the 'buyer' data from the rest. Then add a column for the start of the time interval and do a non-equi join in `data.table`, which is what @chinsoon is suggesting. I've made a reproducible example below:

```r
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
N <- 1e5

# Filter buyer details first
buyer_dt <- data.table(
  tm = Sys.time()+runif(N,-1e6,+1e6),
  quantity=round(runif(N,1,20))
)

time_dt <- data.table(
  t = seq(
    min(buyer_dt$tm),
    max(buyer_dt$tm),
    by = 15*60
  )
)
t_int <- 300
time_dt[,t1:=t-t_int]
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
  a={ # Your sapply code
    bv1 <- sapply(1:nrow(time_dt), function(i){
      buyer_dt[between(tm,time_dt$t[i]-t_int,time_dt$t[i]),sum(quantity)]
    })
  },
  b={ # data.table non-equi join
    all_intervals <- buyer_dt[time_dt,.(t,quantity),on=.(tm>=t1,tm<=t)]
    bv2 <- all_intervals[,sum(quantity),by=.(t)]
  }
  ,replications = 9
)
#>   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
#> 1    a            9   42.75  158.333    81.284    0.276          0
#> 2    b            9    0.27    1.000     0.475    0.000          0
#>   sys.child
#> 1         0
#> 2         0
```

Edit: In general, any join of two tables A and B is a subset of the outer join [A x B]. The rows of [A x B] will have all possible combinations of the rows of A and the rows of B. An equi join will subset [A x B] by checking equality conditions, i.e. If `x` and `y` are the join columns in A and B, Your join will be : rows from [A x B] where `A.x=B.x` and `A.y=B.y`

In a NON-equi join, the subset condition will have comparision operators OTHER than `=`, for example: like your case, where you want columns such that `A.x <= B.x <= A.x + delta`.

I don't know much about how they are implemented, but `data.table` has a pretty fast one that has worked well for me with large data frames.

Comment: Could you explain what is a non-equi join in simple terms way? thanks for the help, by the way!